# Connection failing on openjdk-7-jre

Tags: installation, apt, updates, openjdk

I am trying to install openjdk-7-jre on a 64bit Ubuntu 12.04 server as part of a Canvas LMS install.

When I run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` I get:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe openjdk-7-jre-headless amd64 7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
 Connection failed
```

This error is repeated for `security.ubuntu.com` at two separate locations

I have tried using the `--fix-broken` flag as this was suggested at the first failure, but this has not resolved the issue.

I have installed multiple other packages with no issues, this leads me to believe the I do not have a connectivity issue to the internet or to the repository.

I have run both the apt-get update and the apt-get upgrade with no problems.

Any suggestions as I am unable to complete the LMS install without this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried manually downloading openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb from http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-7/ and the file (which is ~34MB) downloaded successfully. This was less than an hour after you asked your question. Try running:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

Comment: karel, thanks for getting back to me. Just trying the headless failed with the same message. However, your response pointed me to the answer. We run a Sophos WS500 proxy which I was using. It was allowing all the other packages through with no issues, but was stopping the openjdk packages because of data fragmentation..... Removed the proxy settings, set a rule on the firewall to let the server out directly - hey presto, the package now works......